# Invalid Crediential to Clone repo in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

**Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h -- https://bitbucket.org/nallwar/jenkins-docker-sample.git HEAD" returned status code 128:

stdout:

stderr: remote: Invalid credentials

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/nallwar/jenkins-docker-sample.git/'**

i have tried to all the possible ways to resolve the issue like adding SSH key, username with password. its not working as i expected.

i have tried by running **git.exe ls-remote -h -- https://bitbucket.org/nallwar/jenkins-docker-sample.git HEAD** but no use.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue